# Is it possible to order/filter favorites by tags?

Tags: support, bookmarks, bookmark

Is it possible to order or filter bookmarked questions by tags to avoid scrolling favorites for hours when you search for something specific you don't clearly remember because it was long time ago?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is.

For example,

```
infavorites:mine [bug] or [support]
```

searches for your favorite with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [support](/questions/tagged/support).

[Try it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+infavorites%3Amine+%5Bbug%5D+or+%5Bsupport%5D).

Comment: With the current interface of SO the format is   in:saves [tagname]. For eg in:saves[gpu]